# Update UpdatePanel on MasterPage from ContentPage - Dont updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Im trying to refresh content inside UpdatePanel that is on my masterpage from another contentpage

Code i want to update in my usercontrol is inside if that matter, without it code will refresh when i want but also a whole lot of other times i dont want it to refresh.

```
if (!IsPostBack){}
```

Masterpage

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateShoppingCart" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <uc1:ShoppingCart ID="ShoppingCart1" runat="server" />
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Contentpage Product.aspx.cs

```
UpdatePanel panel = (UpdatePanel)this.Form.Parent.FindControl("UpdateShoppingCart");
panel.Update();
```

It don't Update.

Someone wants to show me how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Expose your update panel as a property from your Master Page's code behind:

```
public UpdatePanel updateShoppingCart {get {return UpdateShoppingCart;}}
```

Then set the MasterType proprety on your .aspx page (this will make the master page strongly typed).

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Then on the content page code behind:

```
Master.updateShoppingCart.Update();
```

Comment: public updateShoppingCart {get {return UpdateShoppingCart;}}

**Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct**

Comment: Tried

`                    UpdatePanel panel = (UpdatePanel)this.Form.Parent.FindControl("UpdateShoppingCart");
                    panel.Update();`

But it dont update

Comment: You have to put the property inside your class on the master page's code behind.

Comment: isnt this missing a type? like void string or something: public updateShoppingCart {get {return UpdateShoppingCart;}}

Comment: You can only call the method Update on UpdatePanel with ID UpdatePanel1 when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.

If i do this, it doesn't update

Comment: I think you're finding out some of the limitations of UpdatePanel, it's a very difficult control to work with. You're likely better off in the long run if you reimplement to use a proper client side framework that calls a server side service (such as WCF or Web API) via AJAX.

Comment: OK so what is the best way to do this: My shoppingcart is in a usercontrol thats on the masterpage, then on the product page in add to cart button i want to update my shoppingcart to update the corret totalamount and product count after i inserted the new product.
@mason

Comment: I put the shoppingcart in preerender instead of page load, now it updates

Comment: "The best way" is very subjective. If I were you though, I'd probably implement a [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) hub that provides notifications to the client side when the contents of the shopping cart have changed, and then have JavaScript there update the DOM accordingly. I would definitely steer clear of UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

I put my code in the usercontrol in pre render instead of page load, now it updates and i dont need UpdatePanel